# jQuery flot - don't display -1 on yaxis when there are no value

Tags: jquery, flot

is it possible to prevent flot to show -1 on the yaxis, when there are no values?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

---

// Edit: I'm creating stats graphs for some servers (Accesses per hour). There are some server with no accesses a day, so the flot chart is filled with no data.

Javascript for creating my flot chart:

```
function onOutboundReceived(data) {
    var length = data.length;
    var finalData = data;
    var options = {
        series: {
             lines: {
                 show: true,
                 lineWidth: 2, 
                 fill: true,
                 fillColor: {
                 colors: [{
                     opacity: 0.2
                 },{
                     opacity: 0.01
                 }]
             } 
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        },
            shadowSize: 2
                },
                legend:{
                  show: false
                },
                grid: {
                    labelMargin: 10,
                    axisMargin: 500,
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true,
                    tickColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.22)",
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: 5,
                    tickDecimals: 0
                },
                xaxis: {
                    ticks: 24,
                    tickDecimals: 0
                }
            };
            $.plot($("#stats-"+HSIDarr[i]), finalData, options);
```

Comment: can you provide what you're doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [API doc](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md), you can specify `min` and `max` attributes for an `axis`:

> The options "min"/"max" are the precise minimum/maximum value on the scale. If you don't specify either of them, a value will automatically be chosen based on the minimum/maximum data values.

The example for doing so is in plot initialization:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ], { yaxis: { max: 1 } });
```

And here's snippet demonstrating the `min` and `max` values.

```js
$.plot($("#graph"), [ [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ], { yaxis: { max: 1, min: 1 } });
```

```css
#graph {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<div id="graph" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the min and max values for the y axis in your plot options, see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes).